# objective c textField: selectAll text doesn't always work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, selectall

I implemented this in the UITextField delegate:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)iTextField {
    [iTextField selectAll:iTextField];
}
```

My text field contain text.
When tapping on it, the keyboard goes up and all text selected.
when dismissing the keyboard and tapping again, no text selected (just blinking cursor).
when dismissing the keyboard and tapping again, all text selected again.

Any clue why does no text selected at the second tap?

Comment: How are you dismissing the keyboard exactly?

Comment: with the dedicated key at the keyboard...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

have you tried with this?

```
textField.selectedTextRange = [textField textRangeFromPosition:textField.beginningOfDocument toPosition:textField.endOfDocument];
```

**EDIT 1:**
Now is going to work :), this call will be at the end of the queue

```
[textField performSelector:@selector(selectAll:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
```

Comment: Although Apple may have fixed some part of this problem (selectAll works most of the time for us), there is a new corner case when we test in iOS15.6.1. If the text is longer than will fit in the TextField, then the SelectAll does not work immediately. A second tap is required. And this workaround using performSelector does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I call selectAll in viewDidAppear works.